# Deleted oradata folder under oracle home by accident

Tags: restore, recovery, centos

While setting up a new server, I accidentally deleted the oradata folder in the working Database server.
I have no backup of the working database, I googled and found flashback option to recover, but the oradata folder is deleted, I'm working on centos.

Are there any options to recover the database, it had only 1 schema(user) and sys user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the Fast Recovery Area intact?  Do you have backups?  Have you tried to "undelete" the folder?

Answer (score 1):

> I have no backup of the working database

Sayeth the Wise Man (long *after* everybody else has forgotten that *He* did this as well) ...

> > Any Data of which you do not have [at least] two copies is Data you do not care about.

It's a database.  You *should* care.  You *should* have a Recovery Strategy supported by taking backups.

> Are there any options to recover the database?

Not really, no.

By default, even the Fast Recovery Area (where the Database Flashback logs would be, assuming you'd enabled this feature) is created under oradata so ...    no oradata, no database.

If the machine itself gets backed up and you're *really* lucky, you might get *something* back, but I wouldn't get my hopes up.

Hope it wasn't anything important.